# Get particular data from elastic search

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I executed following query -

> Get _all

It gives json as follows -

```
{
    "d352fe61-b130-4ab4-867c-528ab8e044f9": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "explore": {
                "properties": {
                    "archiveSize": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "05ff14ef-1c39-42b0-9dec-159d009b7fd0": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "archive": {
                "properties": {
                    "archiveSize": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "36bbf96d-d260-4c05-805e-0a1df5098c02": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "explore": {
                "properties": {
                    "archiveSize": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From this I want to get the name of the Indexes where mapping is explore. For example these databases - "d352fe61-b130-4ab4-867c-528ab8e044f9" / "05ff14ef-1c39-42b0-9dec-159d009b7fd0" / "36bbf96d-d260-4c05-805e-0a1df5098c02"

What query should I run in elastic search to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the number sequence eg. 36bbf96d-d260-4c05-805e-0a1df5098c02 is the name of your Index. And explore and archives is name of the "types" in that Index.

You can get the the data entries from an Index of all types by using this query

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/INDEX_NAME/_search?pretty'
```

For getting entries (data) from a particular type in the index you can use

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/INDEX_NAME/TYPE_NAME/_search?pretty'
```

You can use the name by running this

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty'
```

From there you can get the names of the required index by checking their corresponding IDs displayed in the list of indices.

Comment: You can use this `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty'
` to get the names and their ID in your database. From there you can get the name of the required index.